# memory leak in ffmpeg

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, ffmpeg

I have incorporated ffmpeg into an iPad app, and when I stream via rtsp, I see the app crash after a few hours of streaming.

When i debug the app via Instruments/leaks, i found the offending leak is inside an FFMPEG library, and the offending function is av_buffer_realloc.

Does anyone know how I can proceed with getting this leak addressed/fixed? I do not have a lot of tools at my disposal, and I am not even sure where to post to get this problem addressed?

Thank you for any help/suggestions.

as per a request, here is code. BUT, it has nothing to do with MY code, as the streaming is occurring, there is a leak in FFMPEG. Whether I set my timer to 1/30 sec, or 1/60 second, the leak is consistent, and as stated above is in a routine that is not mine - it is in the ffmpeg library.

```
video = [[RTSPPlayer alloc] initWithVideo:szURL usesTcp:NO];
lastFrameTime = -1;
// seek to 0.0 seconds
[video seekTime:0.0];
[_nextFrameTimer invalidate];
self.nextFrameTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/30 target:self selector:@selector(displayNextFrame:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

here is displayNextFrame. It calls into RSTPPlayer to get a snapshot video frame:

```
{
    if (![video stepFrame]) {
        [timer invalidate];
        [video closeAudio];
        return;
    }
    self.theImageView.image = video.currentImage;
}
```

Here is the currentImage code from RTSPPlayer:

```
- (UIImage *)currentImage
{
    if (!pFrame->data[0]) return nil;
    [self convertFrameToRGB];
    return [self imageFromAVPicture:picture width:outputWidth height:outputHeight];
}
```

Here is imageFromAVPicture:

```
- (UIImage *)imageFromAVPicture:(AVPicture)pict width:(int)width height:(int)height
{
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CFDataRef data = CFDataCreateWithBytesNoCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, pict.data[0], pict.linesize[0]*height,kCFAllocatorNull);
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(data);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageCreate(width, 
                                       height, 
                                       8, 
                                       24, 
                                       pict.linesize[0], 
                                       colorSpace, 
                                       bitmapInfo, 
                                   provider, 
                                   NULL, 
                                   NO, 
                                   kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];

CGImageRelease(cgImage);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
CFRelease(data);

return image;
```

}

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Provide your code and the steps to retain the leak.

Answer (score 2):

inside **- (BOOL)stepFrame** function, add

```
av_free_packet(&packet);
```

below

```
avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);
```

Reference: [Github issues](https://github.com/durfu/DFURTSPPlayer/issues/7)